# how to reorder programmatically drupal 7 ubercart 3 attributes

Tags: sorting, drupal-7, ubercart

how can i programmatically arrange or set ordering of attribute

in ubercart3 in drupal7 i tried doing the following:

```
$node = node_load($product_id); 
$node->attributes[1]->ordering = -25; 
$node->attributes[12]->ordering = -24; 
node_save($node);
```

nothing is changed when i saved it.

Can someone help out whats the workaround for this please..

i tried node_presave() hook samething happend, it didnt re-order the products attributes.